# How to loop in array of dictionaries in a list

Tags: python

Trying to loop in an array of dictionary in list I am getting this error message:

> TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not dict

What am I doing wrong here?

```
cars= [ {
      "name": "Ford",
      "type": "SHORT",
      "coded": {
      "1": "Escape",
      "2": "Fiesta",
      "999": "Gumbo"
    }
 },
{
      "name": "Honda",
      "type": "SHORT",
      "coded": {
      "1": "Civic",
      "2": "CRV",
      "VCR": "Accord"
    }
 }
]

for i in cars:
  for x, y in cars[i]["coded"].items():
    print(x, y)
```

I am getting this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 23, in <module>
TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not dict
```

Comment: `i` is a `dict`.  You probably meant either `for i, car in enumerate(cars):` or `for x, y in i["coded"].items():`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you iterate over a list, you get the elements, not the indices. Consider

```
for car in cars:
  for x, y in car["coded"].items():
    print(x, y)
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm really not good with explanations. In case you aren't clear with anything just leave a comment for clarification

`i` in this iteration is going to be

```py
{
   "name": "Ford",
   "type": "SHORT",
   "coded": {
     "1": "Escape",
     "2": "Fiesta",
     "999": "Gumbo"
   }
}
```

and

```py
{
  "name": "Honda",
  "type": "SHORT",
  "coded": {
    "1": "Civic",
    "2": "CRV",
    "VCR": "Accord"
  }
}
```

and not `1 and 2` as you expected anyways a better way of doing this is going to be

```py
cars= [ 
  {
    "name": "Ford",
    "type": "SHORT",
    "coded": {
      "1": "Escape",
      "2": "Fiesta",
      "999": "Gumbo"
    }
  },
  {
    "name": "Honda",
    "type": "SHORT",
    "coded": {
      "1": "Civic",
      "2": "CRV",
      "VCR": "Accord"
     }
   }
]

for i in cars:
  for x, y in i['coded'].items():
    print(x, y)
```

As I have said I'm new to answering questions. Ask for more clarification if needed!